# Arithmetic Progression. Find 1st term and common difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

The seventh term of an A.P. is 15 and the sum of the first seven terms is 42. Find the first term and common difference.

How do I find the first term and common difference with only 1 term given?

Comment: The sum of the first n terms of an AP is $\frac 12 n (FirstTerm + LastTerm)$

Answer (score 1):

Note: use that $$a_7=a_1+6d=15$$ and
$$7a_1+21d=42$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ the common difference of consecutive terms in the progression. We are given that $a_7=15$ and that
$$a_1+\dots+a_7=7\,\frac{a_1+a_7}2=42,\quad\text{so}\quad a_1+a_7=12.$$
On the other hand, the common difference is $\;d=\dfrac{a_7-a_1}6$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_7 = 15$ and $\frac{7(a_1 + a_7)}{2} = 42$.

By plugging in $a_7$ into the second equation, we get $a_1 = -3$.
It follows clearly that the difference between two terms will be $3$.

Answer (score 0):

An arithmetic progression has the form $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d $, where $a_n $ is the general term and $d $ is the common difference...

So, $15=a_7=a_1+(7-1)d=a_1+6d $.  The sum of the first $7$ terms is $42=(7a_1+21d) $.  So $d=\frac {15-a_1}6=\frac{42-7a_1}{21}\iff  a_1= -3$. And, $15=-3+6d$, so $ d=3$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The sum of the first seven terms is $$a_1 + (a_1 + d) + (a_1 + 2d) + (a_1 + 3d) + (a_1 + 4d) + (a_1 + 5d) + (a_1 + 6d) = 7a_1 + \color{red}{21}d$$

Comment: Shame on me :  I missed an opportunity to use gauss’s sum formula. ..